# How to find if element exists in an array in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to render an element after checking whether there is a string e.g. "abc" present in an array. I have tried using various different functions like array.find(), array.includes(), array.some() While I do so, it gives me an error -

> TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'o.includes')

Below is the piece of code that I am using inside render function. "abc" is the array where I am trying to check whether string "a" exists in that array, if it does then display that ExpandedHeader element.

PS: I am new to react-native.

```
<View>
{abc.includes("a") && <ExpandedHeader title={"Got it"} 
       expanded={this.state.riskRatingExpanded}
       onPress={() => {this.setState({
                    riskRatingExpanded :!this.state.riskRatingExpanded,
                    basicDetailsExpanded : false,
                    envProfileExpanded : false,
                    nwswProfileExpanded : false,
                    additionalInfoExpanded : false,
                    scoresExpanded : false,
                  });
             }}

         />}
</View>
```

But instead, if I do the below it works -

```
<View>
    {abc != null && <ExpandedHeader title={abc[0]} 
           expanded={this.state.riskRatingExpanded}
           onPress={() => {this.setState({
                        riskRatingExpanded :!this.state.riskRatingExpanded,
                        basicDetailsExpanded : false,
                        envProfileExpanded : false,
                        nwswProfileExpanded : false,
                        additionalInfoExpanded : false,
                        scoresExpanded : false,
                      });
                 }}

             />}
    </View>
```

Comment: This error means that `abc` is not actually an array (it is actually `null`), you should be able to confirm that with `console.log('abc:', abc);`. Where are you getting that from? Sure you are using the correct selector? Or maybe it needs to be initialized first? Then you'd need to do a `if (abc == null) { return <View /> }` to wait for initialization of the variable first

Comment: To check whether abc is null or not I had done a check, where instead of abc.includes("a"), I had written abc != null (to check if abc is not null then display the Expanded header component) and it does display it. Also, in Expanded header if I write abc[0] instead of string "Got it" it displays string "a".

Comment: I might be that it is initializing, so it will show "a" as soon as you look, but the very first time it will be null. Did you try putting `if (abc == null) { return <View /> }` in your code to make sure it works? You can also put your whole code inside a `if (abc != null) { ... }` to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render function runs before your array data is present and initially your array data is `null`,

make sure you initialise your `abc` state as array first,

`state = {
 abc: []
}`

with this, your first code should work.